# How to add a component library to Flash CS5.5

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, flash-cs5

I want to add [Liquid Components](http://www.bytearray.org/?p=137) to my existing project. I'm new to Flash development so I'm not sure how these components are installed. On the website it says to move .fla file to a specific folder.

I'm using Flash CS5.5 on Windows 7.  I moved Liquid.fla file to: `C:\Users\MyUserName\AppData\Roaming\Adobe\Flash CS5.5\en\Configuration\Components`  Note, there wasn't a Flash CS5.5 folder so I created it, it might not be right name, maybe that is the problem.

I also tried moving .fla file to `C:\Program Files\Adobe\Adobe Flash CS5.5\en_US\Configuration\Libraries`.

When I go to component panel in Flash CS5.5 I don't see these liquid components (even after restarting Flash CS5.5). Am I suppose to see the installed components in Flash CS5.5 Component panel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of putting that in    Roaming folder, put it under "local", like the following

```
C:\Users\MyUserName\AppData\Local\Adobe\Flash CS6\en_US\Configuration\Components\Liquid
```

Mine is Flash CS6, but it should not be much different from CS5.5

Comment: What is the "C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Adobe Flash CS6\Common\Configuration\Components" folder used for?